# PowerShell to create bulk users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to apologize in advance I know this is going to be something I am overlooking but I have spent hours trying to get this to work right. Code is at the bottom.

I am trying to create an automated script to create users based on an email sent to a DL with PowerShell. I am not that versed and have exhausted the web and all the books I have. I have gotten it to work but with some errors.

Errors

1. In AD under the Account tab under the user logon name: the domain field was left empty
2. Under Active Directory Administrative Center, and Attributes. For Proxy the SMTP was not set.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Users = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Script\newusers2022.csv"            
foreach ($User in $Users)            
{            
   $Displayname = $User.FirstName + " " + $User.Lastname            
   $UserFirstname = $User.Firstname            
   $UserLastname = $User.Lastname  
   $UserEmployeeID = $User.EmployeeID          
   $OU = $User.OU           
   $SAM = $User.FirstName + "." + $User.Lastname            
   $UPN = $User.Firstname + "." +  $User.Lastname + "@" + $User.Mydomain.com
   $EmailAddress = $User.Firstname + "." +  $User.Lastname + "@" + $User.Mydomain.com            
   $Description = $User.Description            
   $Password = "RandomColor1" + "RandomGenPass" + "!"     
   New-ADUser -Name $Displayname -DisplayName $Displayname -SamAccountName $SAM -UserPrincipalName $UPN -GivenName $UserFirstname -Surname $UserLastname -Emailaddress $Email -EmployeeID $UserEmployeeID -Description $Description -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -Enabled $true -Path "$OU" -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -PasswordNeverExpires $false
   Write-Host $User.SAM "created successfully"
}
```

Comment: This looks suspicious: `$User.domain.com` - Is that what is actually in your code, or did you change that when posting your question?

Comment: Also, what email system does your organization use (Exchange, Office 365, etc)?

Comment: I changed it when posting the code.

Comment: Office 365 is our email

Comment: This did push fine once I added the SMTP to the proxy and ran the delta sync.

Comment: Depending on your domain infrastructure, some properties are based on each other. Also, as a side note, this would be a good example on when to use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.2).

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I was able to get the first error fixed i am just working on the SMTP error where the email address is not populating to the proxy in Attributes.

Comment: You could try setting `proxyAddresses` manually

Comment: As aside, most domains do not allow a password containing (part of) the username .. and as @GabrielLuci already commented, this is wrong: `$User.domain.com`. Please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71310408/edit) so the mistakes you have put in at the moment of posting do not distract from the real problems you have with your code. Did you see you create a variable called `$EmailAddress`, but on the New-ADUser you suddenly use an undefined variable called `$Email` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the error in my variable. But also added the proxyAddress variable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).